# how to remove the warnings in Jtidy in java

Tags: java, jtidy

I am using Jtidy parser in java.

```
URL url = new URL("www.yahoo.com"); 
HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
InputStream in = conn.getInputStream(); 
doc = new Tidy().parseDOM(in, null);
```

when I run this, "doc = new Tidy().parseDOM(in, null);"
  I am getting some warnings as follows:

```
Tidy (vers 4th August 2000) Parsing "InputStream"
line 140 column 5 - Warning: <table> lacks "summary" attribute

InputStream: Doctype given is "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
InputStream: Document content looks like HTML 4.01 Transitional

1 warnings/errors were found!
```

These warnings are getting displayed automatically on console. But I don't want these
warnings to be displayed on my console after running

```
doc = new Tidy().parseDOM(in, null);
```

Please help me,how to do this,how to remove these warnings from console.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Looking at the Documentation I found a few methods which may do what you want.

There is `setShowErrors`, `setQuiet` and `setErrout`. You may want to try the following:

```
Tidy tidy = new Tidy();
tidy.setShowErrors(0);
tidy.setQuiet(true);
tidy.setErrout(null);
doc = tidy.parseDOM(in, null);
```

One of them may be enough already, these were all the options I found. Note that this will simply hide the messages, not do anything about them. There is also `setForceOutput` to get the output, even if errors were generated.

Answer (score 5):

If you want to redirect the JTidy warnings to (say) a log4j logger, read [this blog entry](http://ideas-and-code.blogspot.com/2009/10/jtidy-errors-to-log4j.html).

If you simply want them to go away (along with other console output), then use `System.setOut()` and/or `System.setErr()` to send the output to a file ... or a black hole.

For JTidy release 8 (or later), the [`Tidy.setMessageListener(TidyMessageListener)`](http://jtidy.sourceforge.net/apidocs/org/w3c/tidy/Tidy.html#setMessageListener%28org.w3c.tidy.TidyMessageListener%29) method deals with the messages more gracefully.

---

Alternatively, you could send a bug report to `webmaster@yahoo.com`. :-)

Answer (score 3):

```
Writer out = new NullWriter();
PrintWriter dummyOut = new PrintWriter(out);
tidy.setErrout(dummyOut);
```

Answer (score 2):

Looking at the documentation I found another method that seems a bit nicer to me in this particular case: `setShowWarnings(boolean)`. This method will hide the warnings, but errors will still be thrown.

For more info look here:
http://www.docjar.com/docs/api/org/w3c/tidy/Tidy.html#setShowWarnings(boolean)

Answer (score 0):

I think this is the nicest solution, based on the answer of Joost:

```
Tidy tidy = new Tidy();
tidy.setShowErrors(0);
tidy.setShowWarnings(false);
tidy.setQuiet(true);
```

All three are necessary.