# how to remove error log in Jtidy?

Tags: java, logging, jtidy

I use code below for jtidy.

```
  Tidy tidy = new Tidy();
  tidy.setQuiet(true);
  tidy.setShowWarnings(false);
  doc = tidy.parseDOM(in, null);
```

it can remove all warning log but i still get error log below

```
  line 424 column 20 - Error:  is not recognized!
  line 481 column 20 - Error:  is not recognized!
```

How can i remove error above? and it looks that i set "show-errors=0" in config file doesn't work either, any ideas? thanks!

jtidy.config:

```
show-warnings=no
show-errors=6
```

Comment: I'm using jtidy-04aug2000r7-dev.jar

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/q/6213764/776084

Comment: it won't work for me, i need to setup a config file this jtidy

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
public void setShowErrors(int showErrors)
```

function, which sets the number of errors to put out. And you should give 0 as a parameter.

Ref: http://jtidy.sourceforge.net/apidocs/org/w3c/tidy/Tidy.html#setShowErrors(int)