# How to Remove all output from JTidy?

Tags: java, xml, jtidy

I'm using JTidy to clean up some XML, like this:

```
Tidy tidy = new Tidy();
tidy.setXmlOut(true);
tidy.setShowWarnings(false);
tidy.parse(new FileInputStream(strStrippedHTMLPath), new FileOutputStream(strXMLPath));
```

The problem is that it always outputs the following:

```
InputStream: Document content looks like HTML 4.01
5 warnings, no errors were found!
```

How can I prevent it from outputting anything? I tried:

```
tidy.setShowErrors(0);
tidy.setQuiet(true);
tidy.setErrout(null);
```

, as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6213764/how-to-remove-the-warnings-in-jtidy-in-java), but that didn't work either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, there's always:

```
PrintStream oldErr = System.err();
ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
PrintStream newErr = new PrintStream(boas);
System.setErr(newErr);
tidy.parse(...);
System.setErr(oldErr);
```

It would be better to use some kind of Null output stream (apparently Apache Commons has such a beast). But the gist of it is the same.

Of course, that's a bit of a hack...

Comment: Just a quick warning: This is not thread safe and will redirect the error output for everything running in the VM, so be sure you know what you're doing!

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `tidy.setErrout(null);`  use `tidy.setErrout(new PrintWriter(new ByteArrayOutputStream()));`
this seems to work for me.